# Configuring individual IdentityServer4 in pool for high availability

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

This is fairly new to me, so I apologize if the terminology is not correct.

We have a service endpoint that validates a token per incoming request.
There is a need for this to be used in a high availability (zero downtime ever allowed) environment and we are currently trying to deal with the following scenario:

- A pool of idps e.g. [A-Z]
- Client is issued token from "A",
- "A" fails
- The request is sent to the server with the Jwt issuer set to "A" on the token.
- The service should be able to validate against a pool of (pre-configured) issuers. In this case, it recognizes that "A" is dead, and tries to validate against any other server, possibly by load balancing, e.g. "B" or "K", which should succeed.

The plan right now is to allow the pool of identity servers to share a pool of, possibly routed by load balancing, replicated databases to store whatever it needs to validate the token, which seem to be the recommended way from docs.

I've read through the Identity Server4 docs, but the deployment section for HA is fairly limited. YouTube videos, forums are great for understanding possible problem profiles, and great as an overview; so far they've all been tangents, however. Other posts on SO that are similar are either unanswered or, again, not related / suitable.

Right now the service configuration looks something like below, with one extended .AddJwtBearer(); per pooled idp. But in the scenario described above, it throws an exception saying "A" is dead and it could not validate the token against any other.

```
.AddJwtBearer("a",
                options =>

                {
                    options.Audience = "x";
                    options.Authority = authSettings.Authority;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters

                    {
                        RoleClaimType = "x",
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                        RequireExpirationTime = authSettings.RequireExpirationTime,
                        ValidAudiences = authSettings.Audiences,
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuers = validIssuers,
                        ValidateLifetime = authSettings.ValidateLifetime
                    };

                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                    {

                        OnMessageReceived = context =>
                        {

                            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                            {

                                accessToken = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
                            }

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                            {
                                context.Token = accessToken.ToString()
                                    .Replace("Bearer ", "");
                            }
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                                context.Request.Headers["Upgrade"] == "websocket")
                            {
                            }

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });
```

I am looking for general advice, reading, other sources and tips that could point me in the right direction to tackle this.

The security is, of course, important, but getting it working is the first step. For those worried, there will be multiple security audits before anything goes live.

Comment: Why in your system the services are validating the tokens through IDPs? Normally tokens are validated by signature and no backchannel comms are required.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Honestly, just inexperience with this. If you have any good references on configuration for authentication of jwt bearers, I'd really appreciate any source!

Comment: Firstly, if you are using non-reference tokens, then tokens are not validated via idp at all, instead they are validated using the signature. So basically your service only needs to contact idp once to retrieve the various config settings and the public key information to validate signature. If you are concerned on availability of that - solve it via infrastructure instead.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I will look into it, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe implement a custom [HttpMessageHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler?view=netframework-4.8) that will fallback to other servers in the pool and apply that via the [JwtBearerOptions.BackchannelHttpHandler property](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/93926543f8469614c2feb23de8a8c0561b8b2463/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerOptions.cs#L64).